# How to toggle current 'active' class of div and remove 'active' class of sibling divs in ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs

I have following code. I want to **toggle** the 'active' class of current div when it is **clicked** and remove the 'active' class of sibling divs. I used ng-repeat

```
<div class="" ng-repeat="data in people">
<p>{{data.name}}</p>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.people=[{
"name" : "john snow"
},
{
"name" : "daenerys"
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the `ng-class` directive.

You need to track the index of the last `selected` value and update the `selected` value using `setActive()`. Call `setActive()` from your HTML on click and pass the index of the object.

Here is a working snippet

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("myCtrl", ["$scope", ($scope) => {
  $scope.people=[{
    "name" : "john snow"
  },
  {
    "name" : "daenerys"
  },
  {
    "name": "stark"
  }];
  
  $scope.selected = null;

  $scope.toggleStatus = (index) => {
      $scope.selected = $scope.selected !== index ? index : null;
  }
}]);
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: yellow;
  // enter active class css here
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="data in people">
      <p ng-class="{active: selected === $index}" ng-click="toggleStatus($index)">
        {{data.name}}
      </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Check out the documentation of `ngClass` for more information here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

Comment: when i click on 'john snow' it is getting highlighted which is working as expected. when i click again on 'john snow' it should remove the highlight.

Comment: Hi, I have made the changes to reflect your desired result @JustCode